# Reputation gets reduced for inactivity?

Tags: support, reputation

I had a reputation score of 1003 but today I found it to be 994, without being down-voted. I admit it's some time before I had any activity but will this bring a penalty? Any other reasons I could have my reputation reduced?

Many thanks

Comment: @RoryAlsop is right in mentioning the recent reputation recalc.  However, you could also check your user profile for recent reputation changes like up/down-votes on your older posts.

Comment: I just reviewed your profile, and it doesn't look like you've had any negative-rep activity logged recently.  So, the recalc must be it.  However, I did notice that a couple of your posts were recently up-voted which put you back around where you started.  ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a look at questions like [this one over on meta stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2251/will-we-get-back-rep-points-lost-after-a-rep-recalc) you will see that Stack Exchange recently updated the way they work rep calculations, and this has had an impact on some people.

As I understand it, you will lose your 1k privileges, as you have dropped under the 1k mark, but this privilege amounts to **Show total up and down vote counts**, and in any case, you are one upvote away from getting it back so I wouldn't worry.

The main impact is on rep from a long time ago, any more recent changes are actually just around when the rep is measured - it is now real time, as opposed to batch calculated.

Comment: 1k also gives the expanded user profile on mouse-over, and allows creation of "gallery" chat rooms.

Comment: Oh - good catch. And now @Georgios is back up over 1k, so all is good :-)

Comment: Thanks for the support and motivation to work towards a higher reputation :-)